# How to use toString two twice in a class on swing components(for combobox)?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, combobox, tostring

I know wrong that's my code. I have two combobox(kalkis and varis). I am overriding with toString this two variables.

```
public class Ucuslar {
    private String KalkisYeri;
    private String VarisYeri;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return KalkisYeri;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return VarisYeri;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMJXd.png)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean, that code is not compiling!! what do you want to do

Comment: you don't override toString per variable. It's done once for the class

Comment: You can't, which one of the (many) reasons I'd don't recommend using it for this purpose, leave `toString` for debugging. Instead, you'll need to supply a `ListCellRenderer` to format the value the way you want depending on how you want to display it

Comment: i want to apply twice toString my fields(varisyeri and kalkisyeri)

Comment: Use getters: public `String getKalkisYeri(){return KalkisYeri;}` and `String getVarisYeri(){return VarisYeri;}`

Comment: Jay Smith, so its not working. 2 combobox result is same

Answer (score 2):

> how to use toString two twice in a class on swing compenents(for
>   combobox)?

You just can not, java doesnt allow that, overriding means you write a custom implementation of a method that the superclass or an interface is offering.

what you need can / must be done another way, you can define getters fro those 2 variables

```
class Ucuslar {
    private String KalkisYeri;
    private String VarisYeri;

    public String getKalkisString() {
        return KalkisYeri;
    }
    public String getVarisString(){
        return VarisYeri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is, you can't (implement two methods with the same signature).

The longer answer to question revolves around needs.  You could seperate your object into two objects, one for each property, then you could override `toString` for each

The other solution would be to implement a custom `ListCellRenderer`s which can be designed to display one of the properties of the object, for example...

```
public class Ucuslar {

    private String KalkisYeri;
    private String VarisYeri;

    public String getKalkisYeri() {
        return KalkisYeri;
    }

    public String getVarisYeri() {
        return VarisYeri;
    }

}

public class UcuslarListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof Ucuslar) {
            configure((Ucuslar)value);
        }
        return this;
    }

    protected void configure(Ucuslar value) {

    }

}

public class KalkisYeriListCellRenderer extends UcuslarListCellRenderer {

    protected void configure(Ucuslar value) {
        setText(value.getKalkisYeri());
    }

}

public class VarisYeriListCellRenderer extends UcuslarListCellRenderer {

    protected void configure(Ucuslar value) {
        setText(value.getKalkisYeri());
    }

}
```

See [How to use combo boxes: Providing a custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more details